Quel est le sens de "finalement" dans cette phrase ?

Est-ce qu'il y a une chose qui t'a marquée ou une chose qui t'a rendu fière ou heureuse ? Est-ce que tu pourrais partager avec nous un succès finalement que tu as rencontré dans une des réunions, une chose qui t'a marquée ?

Quel est le sens de "finalement" dans cette phrase ? On dirait un tic de langage ?
Au début je pensais que cela indiquait que la personne était en train de poser sa dernière question, mais, comme on voit, la dernière a été "une chose qui t'a marquée" et non pas "un succès".

Quand j'étais enfant (Est de la France), bref antéposé tenait le même rôle: Bref, pourrais-tu nous relater un succès que tu as rencontré... Mi-tic de langage, mi-adverbe introduisant une conclusion, une synthèse ou une reformulation. Je suppose que si, de même, finalement était antéposé dans la phrase-exemple, l'OP ne se poserait pas de question.

Mon interprétation est : "... un succès que tu as  finalement rencontré ...", sous-entendu après t'être battu ou au bout du compte.

@Graffito Oui. Ou encore, plus proche de beauchette: "une chose que tu as rencontrée [...] et que finalement, tu vois rétrospectivement comme un succès."

J'y comprends le sens de "en définitive". J'y mettrais même une emphase avec des virgules :

Est-ce qu'il y a une chose qui t'a marquée ou une chose qui t'a rendu fière ou heureuse ? Est-ce que tu pourrais partager avec nous un succès, finalement, que tu as rencontré dans une des réunions, une chose qui t'a marquée ?

Pour ce qui est du sens, je dirais : "en ayant pensé à toutes les possibilités"
